# Форматирование флешки в Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, usb

Я хотел очистить флешку от образа убунту, начал форматировать через файловый менеджер, стирать с нее все файлы, когда начал, флешка исчезла из менеджера, я ее выткнул, комп объявил ошибку форматирования, втыкаю флешку, комп сигнализирует о ней звуковым сигналом, но в файловом менеджере не показывает, я начал сначала ее монтировать с помощью fdisk, но написало, что она не может быть монтирована, потом пытался монтировать с помощью gparted, но там показывает 2 диска: мой ssd и еще какой-то диск на 512 Мб, fdisk флешку видит, но мне нужно привести её в исходное состояние, то есть превратить из загрузочной в обычную. Комп перезагрузил, всё равно нет в файловом менеджере.

Вывод команды `fdisk -l`:

Disk /dev/loop0: 4 KiB, 4096 bytes, 8 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop1: 61,93 MiB, 64913408 bytes, 126784 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop2: 61,93 MiB, 64917504 bytes, 126792 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop3: 54,24 MiB, 56872960 bytes, 111080 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop4: 50,98 MiB, 53432320 bytes, 104360 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop5: 55,5 MiB, 58183680 bytes, 113640 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop6: 219 MiB, 229638144 bytes, 448512 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop7: 43,28 MiB, 45371392 bytes, 88616 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 476,96 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk model: HFM512GDJTNG-8310A
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 66CF1530-89F8-483A-8D5F-541CDF191260

Device           Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1    2048    1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2 1050624 1000214527 999163904 476,4G Linux filesystem

Disk /dev/loop8: 247,93 MiB, 259948544 bytes, 507712 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop9: 65,1 MiB, 68259840 bytes, 133320 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop10: 164,78 MiB, 172761088 bytes, 337424 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop11: 219 MiB, 229638144 bytes, 448512 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop12: 65,22 MiB, 68378624 bytes, 133552 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop13: 43,44 MiB, 45543424 bytes, 88952 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop14: 55,52 MiB, 58204160 bytes, 113680 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/sda: 14,42 GiB, 15472047104 bytes, 30218842 sectors
Disk model: DataTraveler 3.0
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x13ecff58

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *     2048 30218841 30216794 14,4G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)

Comment: Очевидно, что флешка без файловой системы в принципе не способна отобразиться в файловом менеджере и её невозможно примонтировать, это абсолютно нормально

Comment: Фраза «монтировать с помощью fdisk» является бессмысленной, потому что fdisk не предназначен для монтирования и он в принципе не умеет ничего монтировать

Comment: Что мне нужно сделать, чтобы она отобразилась в файловом менеджере?

Comment: Отформатировать. Чтобы можно было попытаться ответить более чётко, покажите как минимум вывод `sudo fdisk -l` или что-то вроде того, а то пока непонятно, что там у вас происходит вообще

Comment: Там слишком много символов для комментария, так что я покажу вывод, относящийся к флешке:

Disk /dev/sda: 14,42 GiB, 15472047104 bytes, 30218842 sectors
Disk model: DataTraveler 3.0
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x13ecff58
Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *     2048 30218841 30216794 14,4G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)

Comment: Поэтому это стоило бы поместить не в комментарий, а в текст вопроса

Comment: В этом вашем виде виден один раздел `/dev/sda1`, его можно отформатировать в FAT32 командой наподобие `sudo mkfs.fat -F 32 /dev/sda1`

Comment: поместил весь вывод в текст вопроса

Comment: А касательно gparted, может, вы просто забыли выбрать другое устройство? Вот тут в менюшке https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0teH.png

Comment: Спасибо большое, ваш совет помог!

Comment: Да, я не выбрал другое устройство, изначально там был выбран ssd.